# Usb external drive on fstab and flush option

Tags: usb

I have an USB external drive. I wish I could put an entry for it in /etc/fstab, so I could put the option 'flush' inside /etc/fstab for that device. The drive's partition is Ext4 and not vfat nor ntfs. The 'flush' option is said to make performance better on I/O operations, since Usb devices seem to freeze when a large amount of data is being transferred. Will the solution work if for some reason the drive is not connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add option  `noauto` meaning do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot time)

and  `nofail` do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

Then it is no problem.

Comment: I noticed that the problem used to happen when using a real-time kernel. I switched to the common kernel and the problem disappeared.